# No Network Access When Connecting to Ethernet Network with 802.1x in Kubuntu

Tags: networking, ethernet, kubuntu, 802.1x

I seem to have exhausted all my possible solutions here. I'm at school and their Wifi is in the process of being fixed/updated. In the mean time, Wired/ethernet would be much more convenient.

I plugged in the ethernet cable, setup the 802.1x authentication in network-manager, and I connected just fine. The problem? I have no network access. I am able to ping the gateway, but nothing is going through.

I understand you have no clue as to the network layout here, but I'm out of ideas and IS won't help because I am not using Windows (that's just infuriating).

According to dhclient, and network manager I was apparently able to successfully authenticate and obtain an IP address. I am able to ping the gateway address shown in a quick run of `route -n`. I have no messages of warnings, errors, or problems with authentication in dmesg.

Lastly, yes I check the browser. There is no browser authentication either. If it is of any use, I know there is a Barracuda filter installed in the network (God, I hate those damn things). I don't know much about the inner workings so I don't know if that could be the problem.

I can't think of any other types of authentication after 802.1x other than browser, and it's not that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are there other workstations you can compare with?  I wonder if the school filters based on MAC address and requires you to pre-register with them.

Comment: It does filter by mac address, but this is an issued computer. I simply put linux onto it. The hardware mac should be fine. Also, i can connect to the same network but wirelessly in other parts of campus.